# Pythonic Way to Sum List of Lists of Strings

Tags: python, string, list, nested

I've found a way to do what I want which is, But I'm wondering if there's a way I can get this down to one line.

I have a list of list of lists of strings, as compared to a lists of numbers (for which there's an answer: [Sum of list of lists; returns sum list)

Example List:

```
list = [['T=-40F A=0K', 'T=-15F A=0K', 'T=59F A=0K', 'T=98F A=0K', 'T=120F A=0K'],
 ['T=-40F A=10K','T=-15F A=10K','T=59F A=10K','T=98F A=10K','T=120F A=10K']]
```

Example Output:

```
['T=-40F A=0K', 'T=-15F A=0K', 'T=59F A=0K', 'T=98F A=0K', 'T=120F A=0K', 'T=-40F A=10K', 'T=-15F A=10K', 'T=59F A=10K', 'T=98F A=10K', 'T=120F A=10K']
```

I can join these with this method:

```
new = []
for i in [['T=%.0fF A=%.0fK'%(t,a)for t in TEMP] for a in ALT]:
    new = new + i
```

Anyone got anything?

As for the application im adding a legend to a matplotlib plot

This would be really easy, and an awesome feature with sum(list)

Comment: How does your input correspond to your output? And what are you trying to do with `new = []` and `new = new + 1`?

Comment: @ Inbar Rose: Im not sure its a duplicate due because all those answers are multi line.

Comment: @hivert : I was looking for something more like what provided Rohit Jain... there's no need to import anything

Comment: @CodeMode Importing modules is not something you should be avoiding - the modules are there for a reason. They provide better, fast implementations of these things for you.

Comment: @CodeMode: Rohit Jain's code is the same as ``comprehension_flatten`` in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using *List Comprehension*:

```
>>> my_list = [['T=-40F A=0K', 'T=-15F A=0K', 'T=59F A=0K', 'T=98F A=0K', 'T=120F A=0K'], ['T=-40F A=10K','T=-15F A=10K','T=59F A=10K','T=98F A=10K','T=120F A=10K']]
>>>
>>> [y for x in my_list for y in x]
['T=-40F A=0K', 'T=-15F A=0K', 'T=59F A=0K', 'T=98F A=0K', 'T=120F A=0K', 'T=-40F A=10K', 'T=-15F A=10K', 'T=59F A=10K', 'T=98F A=10K', 'T=120F A=10K']
```

And you should not use `list` as your variable name.

Comment: Note that a list comp will be slower (and less readable) for this task than `itertools.chain.from_iterable()`.

Comment: Aware of that, but my lists are fairly small. I'm more for reducing total program size i'd rather not import anything

Comment: @CodeMode One line of code is not going to matter in terms of size - it will however make your code more readable and efficient.

Comment: @CodeMode. Please don't be afraid of importing modules. `itertools` is one such precious module, which you will not want to miss, such useful and efficient functions [it provides](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#module-itertools). You should learn using libraries. They are there for some reason.

Comment: In either case thank you both! They are both great solutions and really help me with my engineering workload!

Answer (score 3):

You want to flatten the iterable - [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) exists for that very purpose:

```
>>> data = ...
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(data))
['T=-40F A=0K', 'T=-15F A=0K', 'T=59F A=0K', 'T=98F A=0K', 'T=120F A=0K', 'T=-40F A=10K', 'T=-15F A=10K', 'T=59F A=10K', 'T=98F A=10K', 'T=120F A=10K']
```

It returns an iterator, so you can use `list()` if you *need* a list, or just use the iterator.

Answer (score 2):

You can flatten the list using [`itertools.chain()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain).

```
>>> testList =[['T=-40F A=0K', 'T=-15F A=0K', 'T=59F A=0K', 'T=98F A=0K', 'T=120F A=0K'],
 ['T=-40F A=10K','T=-15F A=10K','T=59F A=10K','T=98F A=10K','T=120F A=10K']]
>>> 
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> chain(*testList)
<itertools.chain object at 0x02B1E910>
>>> list(chain(*testList))
['T=-40F A=0K', 'T=-15F A=0K', 'T=59F A=0K', 'T=98F A=0K', 'T=120F A=0K', 'T=-40F A=10K', 'T=-15F A=10K', 'T=59F A=10K', 'T=98F A=10K', 'T=120F A=10K']
```

**OR** Use `itertools.chain.from_iterable()`

```
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(testList))
['T=-40F A=0K', 'T=-15F A=0K', 'T=59F A=0K', 'T=98F A=0K', 'T=120F A=0K', 'T=-40F A=10K', 'T=-15F A=10K', 'T=59F A=10K', 'T=98F A=10K', 'T=120F A=10K']
```

**P.S** - Please don't use `list` as a variable name, it shadows the builtin.

Comment: Using `*` to unpack the list is inefficient - `from_iterable()` is there for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks! Great response

I should read up on list comprehension

Comment: Didn't know that. Thanks for the comment. Added it to the answer. :)

Comment: @CodeMode There is no [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) here.

Comment: @CodeMode : List comprehension is used in Rohit Jain's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try [itertools.chain.fromiterable()](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) -

```
from itertools import chain
result = list(chain.from_iterable(your_list))
```